# from chalice invoke another lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chalice

HI i am using chalice to deploy rest api's flask python API

**from one chalice lambda to another chalice lambda function**, i am unable to perform triggering

```
from chalice import Chalice
import boto3
import re
import json
import config

@app.on_s3_event(bucket=config.bucket_name, events=['s3:ObjectCreated:Put'],    suffix=config.log_suffix)
def handle_s3_event(event):
"""
response = client.invoke(
FunctionName='string',
InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
LogType='None'|'Tail',
ClientContext='string',
Payload=b'bytes'|file,
Qualifier='string'
)
"""
print("Received event for bucket: %s, key: %s", event.bucket, event.key)
s3_client = boto3.client('lambda')
bucket = event.bucket
key_found = re.findall(config.key, event.key) and "error" not in event.key
print("key is :", key_found)
# if key is 'systemlog' trigger one lambda ...etc
s3_client.invoke(
            FunctionName="arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:120:function:log_file_process-dev",
            InvocationType="RequestResponse",
            Payload=json.dumps({"event_bucket": bucket, "event_key": event.key}))
print("Successfully Sent the request to Child Function.")
```

**child function :**

this is another lambda function created using **Chalice**

```
@app.route("/")
def log_reader(event_key, event_bucket):
    print("***********************************************")
    print("event_key: ", event_key)
    print("event_bucket :", event_bucket)
    print("***********************************************")
```

but i am unable trigger the child function

> I am able to trigger the parent lambda on s3 event , but child function is not triggering from parent  i have used Event/RequestResponse

Comment: What permissions/role is the parent function using? If it does not have Allow: lambda:InvokeFunction it will not be able to make the call. Can you include some logs so we can get a better understanding?

Comment: using the console with the same role , i am able to trigger it but using the chalice it is not working.     for the role i have attached 3 policies (lambda full access, s3 full access and ,lambda invocation) ,for the deployments( console triggering and chalice triggering) i have attached cloud watch logs